# How to pass a procedure as a parameter in Racket Language?

Tags: parameters, lisp, racket

```
(define (remove (lambda) lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      0
      (if ((lambda(car lst) = 'false))
          (cons (car lst '() lambda (cdr lst)))
          (lambda (cdr lst)))))
```

This piece of code is used to check if numbers in list pass the test called lambda, and return a list without the passed element.
So command like (remove `(lambda (x) (= x 0)) (list 0 1 2 3))` would able to pass lambda function as a parameter and use it inside the remove function. How should I do that?

Comment: If you define a function taking a functional parameter, call it as the other parameters: `(define (my-function f x) (... (f x) ...))`, then call your function with the actual function that you want to pass: `(my-function (lambda (x) (= x 0)) (list 1 2 3))`. Note that your function `remove` has many syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are describing is usually known as `(filter)` and it is a standard function in Scheme. A basic implementation might look like this:

```
(define (remove test lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) '())
    ((test (car lst)) (remove test (cdr lst)))
    (else (cons (car lst) (remove test (cdr lst))))))
```

An example of how it would be used might be:

```
(remove (lambda (x)
          (even? x))
        '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
```

The output of which would be

```
'(1 3 5 7)
```

**EDIT**: I also went to the trouble of coming up with a tail-recursive variant which should run in almost-constant space, but is considerably more complicated to read.

```
(define (remove test lst)
  (let loop ((filtered-list '())
             (remainder-list lst))
    (if (null? remainder-list)
        filtered-list
        (let* ((testable-element (car remainder-list))
               (forward-list
                (if (test testable-element)
                    filtered-list
                    (append filtered-list (list testable-element)))))
          (loop forward-list (cdr remainder-list))))))
```

Comment: `filter` is the opposite; it retains the elements for which the predicate is true.